# NSPopUpButton-How to selectively disable some menu items?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a login page in my application with two users-Administrator and Standard. On successful login, we get to the welcome page, where a pop up button is present. I want to disable the 3rd and the 4th menu items in the pop up button menu for the standard user.
For Administrator, all the menu items should be available.
I want this distinction based on the user's selection on the login page.
Please help me, how i can achieve this?
Do i have to use KVC concepts? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to do two things here.

1. To disable your third and fourth menu items, you need to set their `enabled` property to `NO`.

   ```
   [[yourPopUpButton itemAtIndex:2] setEnabled:NO];
   [[yourPopUpButton itemAtIndex:3] setEnabled:NO];
   ```
2. Set `autoenablesItems` property of `NSPopUpButton` to `NO`.

   ```
   [yourPopUpButton setAutoenablesItems:NO];
   ```

   If you don't set this, the menu items will be automatically enabled when you click the pop up button, even though you disable them using Step 1.

Do these things in the `-(void)awakeFromNib` method.

---

For storing the login data to a persistent storage, you can use `NSUserDefaults`. For example.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; // LINE 1: create userDefaults instance
[userDefaults setObject:@"enteredUserType" forKey:@"UserType"]; // LINE 2: store a value
NSString *userType = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"UserType"]; // LINE 3: retrieve the value
```

Here, `UserType` is a user defined Key. You can define any key you want.

Comment: I have tried this in the init method for the WelcomePage class.  My init method looks like this:  -(id) init{  ......
    self=[super init];  ........
    if (self) {  ......
        [actionList setAutoenablesItems:NO];  .........
        [[actionList itemAtIndex:2]setEnabled:NO];  .........
        [[actionList itemAtIndex:3]setEnabled:NO];  ........
        return self;  ..........
    }  ........
}  ..........What is wrong in this?

Comment: You are creating the `UI` using `Interface Builder`? If you are doing so, the button has not yet been initialized inside your `init` method. Try this code, some where else, after the `init` method exits.

Comment: Well i dont seem to understand where else to put this code then. Can u suggest any delegate methods that can be used for this, as in as soon as the WelcomePage window is launched, the delegate method should be called?

Comment: Also, how to make the distinction between the type of user?

Comment: `windowDidUpdate:` delegate method gets triggered after the window loads. You can do that operation in this method. Though, I am not sure whether this method is the right place to do that operation. I am also new to mac.

Comment: Hey! i used the delegate method windowDidUpdate: and it actually worked :). So that part of the problem is solved. However, now i am stuck at Keeping a record of the user entered data on the login page for the welcome page. I need this so as to distinguish between the type of user-Administrator or standard.

Comment: For logging in purposes usually some persistent storage is used for storing login data. You try using `userdefaults`. Save the value to userdefaults when user clicks login-button in login-page. In the welcome-page retrieve the data from userdefaults and do your condition checking.

Comment: is userdefaults a predefined keyword?

Comment: From your answer, Would i be able to user the "userDefaults" across all the classes in my application??

Comment: You have to use LINE 1 to create an instance of `NSUserDefaults` wherever you want to set/get the values.

Comment: An interesting addition to this is that if you are using bindings in combination with programmatically enabling an NSPopUpButton make sure you set enable after you apply the binding otherwise the binding setup enables the popup button.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4:

```swift
// Example NSPopUpButton
@IBOutlet weak var examplePopUpButton: NSPopUpButton!

// Set programatically or in Interface Builder
examplePopUpButton.autoenablesItems = false

// Change programmatically as needed
if let menuitem = examplePopUpButton.item(at: someIndex) {
    menuitem.isEnabled = false // or true
}
```